# How to merge multiple rows into one row using stored procedure in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

There are three tables

1. Asset : AssetId, IsDeleted
2. Tracking : TrackingId, AssetId, TrackingStatusId, TrackingDate
3. TrackingStatus : TrackingStatusId, TrackingStatusName, IsDeleted

I want to make Graph of Asset Vs Status means How many percentage Assets are available in particular status.

**Stored Procedure :**

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Sp_Asset_VS_Status] 

@TimeSpan nvarchar(30),
@Duration int    

as    

begin    

Declare @TotalAsset int;  

select @TotalAsset=COUNT(AssetId) from Asset where Isdeleted=0  

if @TotalAsset>0

Begin  

if @TimeSpan='h'

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
and Tracking.TrackingDate between DATEADD(HOUR,-@Duration,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  
End

else if @TimeSpan='d'

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
and Tracking.TrackingDate between DATEADD(DAY,-@Duration,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  
End

else if @TimeSpan='w'

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
and Tracking.TrackingDate between DATEADD(WEEK,-@Duration,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  
End

else if @TimeSpan='m'

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
and Tracking.TrackingDate between DATEADD(MONTH,-@Duration,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  
End

else if @TimeSpan='y'

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
and Tracking.TrackingDate between DATEADD(YEAR,-@Duration,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  
End

Else

begin
select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage, TrackingStatusName from Tracking   
inner join TrackingStatus on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
Group by TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName order by TotalPercentage DESC  

End

End

End
```

So I am getting result in descending order.

[image]

I want to display first 6 rows from query. First 5 rows as it is and 6 row is sum of all Total Percentage starting from 6th row as shown in figure.

**So after fifth row, How to merge rows into one row and display as others???**

Answer (score 0):

Since the Status field value from the 6th record onwards starts with the word "status", you can use the following statement for your 6th/last query in your SQL block and that should give you 1 row that adds up the TotalPercentages for all "status" rows.

```
begin
    select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage
          ,SUBSTRING(UPPER(TrackingStatusName), 1, 6) 
      from Tracking   
     inner 
      join TrackingStatus 
        on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
     where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
     Group 
        by SUBSTRING(UPPER(TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusName), 1, 6) 
     order 
        by TotalPercentage DESC  

End
```

In response to the comment, the below updated SQL should work, it should 'Others' as the second column for the last SQL

```
begin
    select (100*Count(distinct AssetId))/12 as TotalPercentage
          ,SUBSTRING(STUFF(TrackingStatusName, PATINDEX('%______%', TrackingStatusName), 6, 'Others'), 1, 6) 
      from Tracking   
     inner 
      join TrackingStatus 
        on TrackingStatus.TrackingStatusId=Tracking.TrackingStatusId   
     where Tracking.IsDeleted=0 and TrackingStatus.IsDeleted=0 
     Group 
        by SUBSTRING(STUFF(TrackingStatusName, PATINDEX('%______%', TrackingStatusName), 6, 'Others'), 1, 6) 
     order 
        by TotalPercentage DESC  

End
```

Comment: it is not necessary that every time 6th record starting from status-1. status-1 is a dummy name. It may be any name. I just want to merge all rows from 6th record and give status Name as Others.

Comment: Updated the answer to show 'Others' in status name. I think this should work.